# laravel bootstrap- how to align sidebar to fit different screens?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I created a sidebar for my items page and I want it to fit on the top left but it's out of alignment like below:

[image]

I figured I have to use CSS to style my `list-group-item` class but using `top` and `bottom` does not seem to work at all. Wrapping them in a container also does not give me the desired result. This is my code for below:

```
@extends('layouts.shop.main')

@section('content')




<div>
    {{ Breadcrumbs::render('shop.category.subcategory', $category, $subcategory) }}


  <div class="container">
            <div class="row">        
              <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 col-6">
                <div class="dropdown">
                  <button class="btn btn-default round-background " type="button" id="menu1" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <img src="{{asset('images/bedsheet.jpg')}}" style=" border-radius: 50%;  height: 150px; ">    
                  </button><hr>
                  <span class="text-capitalize"><strong>Bed Sheet</strong></span>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
                    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Sub Item 1</a></li><hr>
                    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Sub Item 2</a></li><hr>
                    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Sub Item 3</a></li><hr>
                    <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Sub Item 4</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>  
              </div>  
              <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 col-6">
                <div class="dropdown">
                  <button class="btn btn-default round-background " type="button" id="menu1" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <img src="{{asset('images/curtain.jpg')}}" style=" border-radius: 50%;  height: 150px;">    
                  </button><hr>
                  <span class="text-capitalize"> <strong>Curtain</strong> </span>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
                    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Sub Item 1</a></li><hr>
                    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Sub Item 2</a></li><hr>
                    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Sub Item 3</a></li><hr>
                    <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Sub Item 4</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div> 
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 col-6">
                <div class="dropdown">
                  <button class="btn btn-default round-background " type="button" id="menu1" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <img src="{{asset('images/pink-bed-sheet.jpg')}}" style=" border-radius: 50%;  height: 150px;">    
                  </button><hr>
                  <span class="text-capitalize"> <strong>Curtain</strong> </span>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
                    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Sub Item 1</a></li><hr>
                    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Sub Item 2</a></li><hr>
                    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Sub Item 3</a></li><hr>
                    <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Sub Item 4</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div> 
              </div>


              <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 col-6">
                <div class="dropdown">
                  <button class="btn btn-default round-background " type="button" id="menu1" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <img src="{{asset('images/curtain.jpg')}}" style=" border-radius: 50%;  height: 150px;">    
                  </button><hr>
                  <span class="text-capitalize"> <strong>Curtain</strong> </span>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
                    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Sub Item 1</a></li><hr>
                    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Sub Item 2</a></li><hr>
                    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Sub Item 3</a></li><hr>
                    <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Sub Item 4</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div> 
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>


    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
            <!-- Options / Recommendation -->
            <div  >
                <!-- Related Categories -->
                <ul class="list-group" >
                    <li class="list-group-item" >

                        <ul class="list-group" >

                            @foreach ($allCategories as $relatedCategory)
                            <li class="list-group-item">
                                <a class="text-capitalize" style="font-weight: 520;" href="/shop/category/{{ $relatedCategory->slug }}">{{ $relatedCategory->name }}</a>

                                @if($relatedCategory->id == $category->id)
                                 <ul class="list-group">
                                    @foreach($category->subcategories as $childCategory)
                                    <li class="list-group-item">
                                         <a class="text-capitalize" style="font-weight: 490;" href="/shop/category/{{ $category->slug }}/{{ $childCategory->slug }}">{{ $childCategory->name }}</a> 
                                        @if($childCategory->id == $subcategory->id)
                                        <ul class="list-group">
                                            @foreach($subcategory->types as $childType)
                                            <li class="list-group-item">
                                                <a class="text-capitalize" style="font-weight: 400;" href="/shop/category/{{ $category->slug }}/{{ $childCategory->slug }}/{{ $childType->slug }}">{{ $childType->name }}</a>
                                            </li>
                                            @endforeach 
                                        </ul>
                                        @endif
                                    </li>
                                    @endforeach
                                </ul> <br>

                             @endif 
                            </li>
                            @endforeach
                        </ul> <br>
                        <ul> 
                            <strong>PRICE</strong>
                               <li>Under RM25 </li> 
                               <li>RM 25 to RM 50 </li>
                               <li>RM50 to RM100 </li>
                               <li>RM100 to RM200 </li>
                               <li>RM200 & Above </li>

                               <input type="number" placeholder="Min" id="quantity" name="quantity" min="1" max="300">
                               <input type="number" placeholder="Max" id="quantity" name="quantity" min="1" max="300">
                               </ul> <br>

                               <ul>
                               <strong>COLOR</strong>
                               <li><input type="checkbox" id="white" name="white" value="white">
                                   <label for="white">WHITE</label>
                               </li><br>
                               <li><input type="checkbox" id="beige" name="beige" value="beige">
                                   <label for="beige">BEIGE</label>
                               </li><br>
                               <li><input type="checkbox" id="red" name="red" value="red">
                                   <label for="red">RED</label>
                               </li><br>
                               <li><input type="checkbox" id="maroon" name="maroon" value="maroon">
                                   <label for="beige">MAROON</label>
                               </li><br>
                               <li><input type="checkbox" id="grey" name="grey" value="grey">
                                   <label for="grey">GREY</label>
                               </li><br>
                               <li><input type="checkbox" id="black" name="black" value="black">
                                   <label for="black">BLACK</label>
                               </li><br>
                               </ul>

                               <ul>
                                  <strong>RATINGS</strong> 
                                  <li>
                                   <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                                   <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                                   <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                                   <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                                   <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>

                               </li>
                               <li>
                                   <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                                   <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                                   <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                                   <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                                   <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                                          and up
                               </li>
                               <li>
                                   <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                                   <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                                   <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                                   <span class="fa fa-star "></span>
                                   <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                                          and up
                               </li>
                               <li>
                                   <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                                   <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                                   <span class="fa fa-star "></span>
                                   <span class="fa fa-star "></span>
                                   <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                                          and up
                               </li>
                               <li>
                                   <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                                   <span class="fa fa-star "></span>
                                   <span class="fa fa-star "></span>
                                   <span class="fa fa-star "></span>
                                   <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                                          and up
                               </li>
                               </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>


            </div>

        </div>


    </div>    

</div>

  @endsection

@push('style')

<style>
.list-group-item {
        border: 0;
        right:50%;
        top:20%;

    }


.round-background {
  height: 170px;
  width: 170px;
  background-color:  ;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}


.checked {
  color: orange;
}

</style>
@endpush
```

I also want it to be responsive so when I shrink my screen to a mobile layout, the sidebar should move below the items but I am not sure how to make it work. Can someone point out my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The container will centre everything and the row is your wrapper for columns so you only want one of each of these. Add the menu above the rest of the content immediately below `<div class="row">`.

Comment: You mean place everything in the same container -> row?

Comment: Yes but the problem is the images are blurry

Comment: see this post i made: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60726978/css-grid-how-to-align-images-size-accordingly

Comment: The images being blurry have nothing to do with this question. If the answer was correct, please accept it as the correct answer. You have another that I answered for you too, also not accepted.